# Can I use a 4 letter acronym of a state agency in my app

Tags: intellectual-property

So I have made an android weather app which uses data from a state environment agency which is referred to as SORA (acronym). The name of my app is "SORA weather - unofficial".

So I have been notified from their PR team that I should remove the acronym part from my app's name, since people could think its theirs. The fact is I am not misleading anyone to think this app is actually theirs since it is obviously "unofficial" written on it. I have also checked in the registry for intellectual property and that acronym is not registered.

So am I free to use the name without any legal issues?

Comment: Why would you want to use their name? It seems pretty misleading to use the name of another agency except to imply it is made or endorsed by them.

Comment: You say "_The fact is I am not misleading anyone_", but the best you can claim is that you aren't _intending_ to mislead... the presence of "SORA" is likely to make at least some people to think it's official. If you _really_ don't want to mislead, simply leave the acronym out.

Comment: I am using their name because it is easily recognizable and also because they are the source of the data. Well my app is a direct copy of what is shown on their website. The thing is that they are never intending to make an official mobile app. So I am trying to create an experience close to what an official app would look like.

Comment: Is the data published under terms of service or similar conditions on its use?  Have you read them?  "I have been notified from their PR team that...": If it's truly the PR team then ask them to refer you to the legal team.  If what you're doing is legal then that's the last you'll hear of it.  If the legal team sends you a letter then you can consider whether you want to comply with their demand or seek a lawyer's advice.

Comment: @phoog Yes, I read the terms of service. It is free to use, so no issues there. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I asked about the terms of service not only to establish that the data are free to use but because they often mention conditions placed on the use.  I would think a requirement to identify the source of the data would be more likely than a prohibition on doing so.  But I checked the public APIs of two national weather offices and didn't find terms of service, much less terms of service that address this issue.